# Type inference issue with Swift's Double initializer for shifted integer parameters

Tags: swift, type-inference

I am trying to initialize a Float or Double with the result of an integer bit shifting operation. The passed parameter is an integer literal, shifted by an unsigned byte. As far as I understand Swift's type inference, that parameter should be of type Int. However, the resulting floating point value is 0.0. Oddly, the issue is gone as soon as I put the parameter expression in brackets.

```swift
let someByte = UInt8(16)

print(Double(1 << someByte)) //Prints "0.0" ?!
print(Double((1 << someByte))) //Prints "65536.0"
```

Comment: Wow, that's definitely a bug – adding parentheses to an expression like that shouldn't change how it's type checked. It looks like in the first case the compiler is choosing `init(_ x: UInt8)` (thus the value is truncated), whereas in the second case it's choosing `init(_ x: Int)`. This does seem to be fixed on master though.

Comment: It seems like a compiler bug. Meanwhile you can use it like this, it works: `let comp = 1 << someByte` `print(Double(comp))`

Comment: `Double.init(1 << someByte)` also appears to work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the compiler. As @Hamish said, the latest master has this problem fixed, I can confirm that as I have the toolchains for Swift 4.2 and Swift 5.0 installed:

- with the Swift 4.2 toolchain the behaviour is as you described: the first print outputs `0.0`, while the second one outputs `65536.0`
- while if using the latest Swift 5.0 toolchain, both calls print `65536.0`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback (also to @Hamish and @Edu), guess I'll have to wait for Swift 5.0 then. Interesting fact: If you create your own class with overloaded initializers, the bug strikes, too. But not for normal functions, only for initializers in "short notation" (`MyClass(...)` instead of `MyClass.init(...)`).